# Does TripAdvisor have pagination?

Tags: api, pagination, offset, tripadvisor

Does anyone know if TripAdvisor has pagination in any of their functions but it's undocumented? Seems bizarre to me that you wouldn't have pagination functionality built in but I don't see anything about it in their documentation?

If it's not there, how could I replicate it to get a decent spread on the returned locations?

https://www.tripadvisor.com/developers

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As of today, TripAdvisor API v1.0 limits all endpoints to a pretty low number of max returned items, so paging becomes pointless.
The (low) limit is different for each endpoint - all is listed in the [API reference](https://tripadvisor-content-api.readme.io/reference/overview), which I cite below.

- Note that their public API - used when you browse the TripAdvisor website - is https://www.tripadvisor.com/data/graphql/ids, and unsurprisingly it has an `offset` property for paging.
  But be adivsed to not go the scraping route, as it violates their [Terms of Use](https://tripadvisor.mediaroom.com/us-terms-of-use).

Here are the API response items limits:

> **Find Search**
> The Location Search request returns **up to 10** locations found by the given
> search query.

> **Nearby Search**
> The Nearby Location Search request returns **up to 10** locations found
> near the given latitude/longtitude.

> **Location Photos**
> The Location Photos request returns **up to 2** high-quality photos for a
> specific location. The photos are ordered by recency.

> **Location Reviews**
> The Location Reviews request returns **up to 3** of the most recent
> reviews for a specific location.

In case you're in a need for more (and you probably do), you are required to contact them, but only if the following apply ([FAQ](https://tripadvisor-content-api.readme.io/reference/faq#how-do-i-get-more-reviews-and-photos)):

> Once your website/app has been up and running successfully with our content for a while and you required more reviews and photos, please reach out to [...] to request more data.