# Can't get all results in tripadvisor using python al beautifulsoup due to pagination

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrape, tripadvisor

I am trying to get links of restaurants but i can only get the first 30 and not all the others.
Restaurants in Madrid Area are hundreads, the pagination only shows 30 in each page and the following code only get those 30

```
import re
import requests
from openpyxl import Workbook
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as b

city_name = 'Madrid'
geo_code = '187514'

headers = {
"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)       Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
}

data = requests.get(
"https://www.tripadvisor.com//Restaurants-g{}-{}.html".format(geo_code, city_name), headers=headers
).text

for link in re.findall(r'"detailPageUrl":"(.*?)"', data):
        print("https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/" + link)
        next_link = "https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/" + link
        f.write('%s\n' % next_link)
```

Comment: Is it possible that the API you are working with uses pagination? In other words, due to the large amount of data, it only returns 30 responses at once? It would be great if you could provide some insight into the data retrieved.

Comment: In this case, the matter is relatively clear: You send only one request and get the first page as a response, which you then evaluate. In order to be able to process all data sets, several requests are necessary, each of which must retrieve the next page (e.g. in a loop). Maybe this could also help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73256976/does-tripadvisor-have-pagination

Comment: i see in documentation the range, but i can't figure out what changes goes in the url

Comment: This depends heavily on how the pagination is implemented. With some APIs, the offsets are specified in the URL, while with some they are specified in an HTTP header. Can you provide a link to the doc?

Comment: https://www.tripadvisor.com//Restaurants-g187514-Madrid.html

Comment: I meant the API documentation on pagination.

Comment: cheers mju but i don't have the API documentation

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, had to add ao with number of the result in the url like:

```
"https://www.tripadvisor.com//Restaurants-g{}-{}-{}.html".format(geo_code, city_name, n_review), headers=headers
```